# Angular service testing promises

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, service

I found myself in a little callback hell and found it difficult to test.
I hope maybe some of you guys could help me to figure this out

I have 2 services and my problem is with the fooService.getModel function

```
app.service('fooService', function($q, barService){
  return {
    getModel: function(){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      barService.get().then(function(response){
        //my bareService mock allow me to reach up to this point
        var result = {};
        //some processing logic (if, else, etc)
        console.log('resolve result') // I totally see this log
        deferred.resolve(result); //this is what i want to test
      });  
      return deferred.promise;
    },
    process: function(){
      this.getModel().then(function(result){
        if(result.success){
            barService.post().then(function(){
               //whatever i dont care
            })
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

and barService which contain 2 methods(get and store) basically $http calls.
for bar service i dont have problems testing because logic is isolated 
I'm just faking the $httpBackend calls, with different responses.

the problem that i found when i want to verify the result object being returned on getModel function.

my test is something like

```
 it('should test the returning model', inject(function(fooService){
     barService.get.and.returnValue({then: function(successCallback){
        successCallback({status:204, data: {}});
     }});

     var result;
     fooService.getModel().then(function(response){
        console.log('unit test then') // never gets in here
        result = response;
     });

     //or anything related to the result object
     expect(result).toEqual(mockedModel); 
     expect(result.success).toBeTruthy()
})
```

what i have seen is that if my getModel function will execute the http call itself, i can evaluate the result in my unit test.

something like

```
getModel: function () {
   var deferred = $q.defer();

   $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
      deferred.resolve(response);
   })
   .catch(function (response) {
      deferred.reject(response);
    });

   return deferred.promise;
}
```

i would definetly love to extract the functionality of my barService to my fooService, but this is very likely to be rehusable that why i extracted to a separate service.

do you have any idea how can i fix my unit test to evaluate the result response?

i hope its clear
thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

nevermind found that i even it is a service, i need to do $scope.digest in my unit test.

thanks!